# Uncaught TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_7__vanilla_tabs__ is not a constructor

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I am trying to import an ES6 module and getting the error. The Modules is a Pure Javascript Tabs that would turn into a responsive accordion. Below you should find link to the Javascript, My main-js and the Javascript for the module.

https://github.com/ADTC/vanilla-tabs

My main.js file:

```
import VanillaTabs from './vanilla-tabs';

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
            new VanillaTabs({
                'selector': '.tabs', // default is ".tabs"
                'type': 'horizontal', // can be horizontal / vertical / accordion
                'responsiveBreak': 840, // tabs become accordion on this device width
                'activeIndex' : 0 // active tab index (starts from 0 ). Can be -1 for accordions.
            });
        });
```

Here's what the module looks like:

```
class VanillaTabs {

    constructor( opts ) {

        const DEFAULTS = {
            'selector': '.tabs',
            'type': 'horizontal',
            'responsiveBreak': 840,
            'activeIndex' : 0
        }

        this.options = Object.assign( DEFAULTS, opts );
        this.elems = document.querySelectorAll( this.options.selector );

        // skip building tabs if they were already initialized
        this.skipIfInitialized = ( tabsElem ) => {

            // skip element if already initialized
            if( tabsElem.classList.contains('tabs__initialized') ) {
                return;
            }

        }

        this.buildUI();
        this.handleNavigation();
        this.handleResponsive();

    }

    // initialize the UI Elements
    buildUI(){

        let tabs = this.elems;

        // walk on all tabs on the page
        tabs.forEach( ( el, i ) => {


            let tabsElem = el,
            childNodes = tabsElem.childNodes,
            tabsTitles = [],
            tabsStyle = this.options.type;

            this.skipIfInitialized( tabsElem );

            tabsElem.classList.add( 'style__' + this.options.type );
            tabsElem.classList.add( 'tabs__initialized' );

            for( let i = 0; i < childNodes.length; i++ ) {

                let tabItem = childNodes[i];

                if ( tabItem.nodeType != Node.TEXT_NODE ) {

                    // add tab__content CSS class
                    tabItem.classList.add( 'tabs__content');

                    // grab tab title from data attribute
                    let tabTitle = tabItem.dataset.title ? tabItem.dataset.title : '';
                    tabsTitles.push( tabTitle );

                    // wrap tab content
                    let tabContent = tabItem.innerHTML;
                    tabItem.innerHTML = '<div class="tabs__content_wrapper">' + tabContent + '</div>';

                    // insert nav link for accordion navigation
                    tabItem.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<a class="tabs__nav_link">' + tabTitle + '</a>');

                }

            }

            // create horizontal / vertical tabs navigation elements
            let navElemsHTML = '';

            tabsTitles.forEach( ( title ) => {
                navElemsHTML = navElemsHTML + '<a class="tabs__nav_link">' + title + '</a>';
            });

            tabsElem.insertAdjacentHTML( 'afterbegin', '<li class="tabs__nav">' + navElemsHTML + '</li>');

            // set initial active tab
            let activeTabIndex = Number( this.options.activeIndex );

            // validate active tab index. but, you can specify -1 for accordion tabs to make all of them closed by defaults
            if( tabsStyle != 'accordion' && activeTabIndex != -1 ) {
                if( activeTabIndex > (tabsTitles.length - 1) ) {
                    console.warn( 'VANILLA TABS: Active tab number from settings is bigger than tabs count. Please remember, that index starts from Zero! To avoid crashes, activeIndex option was reverted to 0.');
                    activeTabIndex = 0;
                }

                tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__nav > .tabs__nav_link')[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active' );
                tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__content')[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active' );
                tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__content > .tabs__nav_link')[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active' );

            }

        });

    }

    // navigation: assign click events
    handleNavigation() {

        let tabs = this.elems,
        tabsStyle = this.options.type;

        // walk on all tabs on the page
        tabs.forEach( ( el, i ) => {

            let tabsElem = el;

            this.skipIfInitialized( tabsElem );

            tabsElem.addEventListener( 'click', function( e ){

                if( e.target && e.target.classList.contains( 'tabs__nav_link') ) {
                    e.preventDefault();

                    let activeTabIndex;

                    // if we click on main navigation link
                    if( e.target.parentElement.classList == 'tabs__nav' ) {
                        activeTabIndex = Array.prototype.slice.call( e.target.parentElement.children ).indexOf( e.target );

                    // if we click on accordion nav link
                    } else {
                        activeTabIndex = Array.prototype.slice.call( e.target.parentElement.parentElement.children ).indexOf( e.target.parentElement ) - 1;
                    }

                    let tabsContent = tabsElem.getElementsByClassName( 'tabs__content'),
                    mainNavLinks = tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__nav > .tabs__nav_link'),
                    accordionNavLinks = tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__content > .tabs__nav_link');

                    // toggle accordion panel
                    if( ( tabsStyle == 'accordion' || tabsElem.classList.contains( 'is__responsive') ) && e.target.classList.contains( 'is__active') ) {
                        tabsContent[ activeTabIndex ].classList.remove( 'is__active');
                        mainNavLinks[ activeTabIndex ].classList.remove( 'is__active');
                        accordionNavLinks[ activeTabIndex ].classList.remove( 'is__active');
                        return;
                    }

                    // remove active class for inactive tabs
                    for( let i = 0; i < tabsContent.length; i++ ) {
                        tabsContent[ i ].classList.remove( 'is__active');
                    }

                    // add active class for a current (active) tab
                    tabsContent[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active');

                    // add active classes and remove inactive for main nav links
                    mainNavLinks.forEach( ( el ) => {
                        el.classList.remove( 'is__active');
                    });

                    mainNavLinks[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active');

                    // add active classes and remove inactive for accordion nav links
                    accordionNavLinks.forEach( ( el ) => {
                        el.classList.remove( 'is__active');
                    });

                    accordionNavLinks[ activeTabIndex ].classList.add( 'is__active');

                }

            });

        });

    }

    // responsive: tabs to accordion
    handleResponsive() {

        let tabs = this.elems,
        responsiveClassName = 'is__responsive',
        tabsStyle = this.options.type;

        window.addEventListener( 'resize', () => {

            // walk on all tabs on the page
            tabs.forEach( ( el, i ) => {

                let tabsElem = el,
                tabsContent = tabsElem.getElementsByClassName( 'tabs__content'),
                mainNavLinks = tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__nav > .tabs__nav_link'),
                accordionNavLinks = tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__content > .tabs__nav_link');

                this.skipIfInitialized( tabsElem );

                if( window.innerWidth > Number( this.options.responsiveBreak ) ) {

                    tabsElem.classList.remove( responsiveClassName );

                    if( tabsStyle != 'accordion' ) {
                        // set first active tab if all of tabs were closed in accordion mode
                        let openTabs = tabsElem.querySelectorAll( '.tabs__nav_link.is__active');
                        if( openTabs.length == 0 ) {
                            tabsContent[0].classList.add('is__active');
                            mainNavLinks[0].classList.add('is__active');
                            accordionNavLinks[0].classList.add('is__active');
                        }
                    }

                } else {

                    tabsElem.classList.add( responsiveClassName );

                }

            });

        });

        // manually fire resize event
        window.dispatchEvent( new Event( 'resize' ));

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `vanilla-tabs` module doesn't actually export the class. To be able to import it as the default, like you're doing in your main file, change the first line of the module to:

```js
export default class VanillaTabs {
```

(Webpack obscures the error message too much here. The error I get from your code using uncompiled ES6 modules directly with Node.js is clearer:)

```html
SyntaxError: The requested module './vanilla-tabs.mjs' does not provide an export named 'default'
```